# What deep sky blue flower is this?

Tags: identification, flowers

What flower is this, and how to collect seeds?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

[image: Blue Morning Glory]This is a stunning blue Morning Glory.  Not sure of the variety.  [morning glory blue](http://www.esfiro.cat/keys/blue-morning-glory-flowers/)  Possibly Ipomea purpurea?  In the family Convolvulaceae. Lots of confusion with the scientific nomenclature.

Allow the flowers to do their thing on the vine.  These are prolific seeders. Annuals sometimes are more persistent than perennials!  A few of the species of Morning glory are perennials in warmer climes.

Comment: I have these climbing on my fences. A joy all summer :)